# Visual Studio share Form(dll) between different solutions without local copy

Tags: visual-studio, dll, shared-libraries

Iam trying to share a DLL file between three Solutions. The idea is to maintain only one dll. If one of the programs is starting it will use this shared dll.

I know there is a "local copy" switch but the result of "False" is, that the program is looking for the file in its own folder instead of using the Path of the reference.

Or is there another way of sharing the Form without maintaining every single Form on its own?

Thank You

Comment: Copy Local = True ensures that you can debug your project.  How you are going to deploy it is up to you.

Comment: But how can I trick VS into using only one dll file and wont copy this dll file into the bin folder

Comment: By setting Copy Local to *False*.  But with the most obvious side-effect that it is pretty unlikely that you can now debug your program since it can no longer find the DLL.  That will happen on the user's machine as well, you cannot delay thinking about how you are actually going to share the DLL.  Copying it to a directory that's on the PATH is the usual hack.  Only real advantage is that you'll now learn a lot more about the consequences of "DLL Hell".

Comment: I dont like the DLL Hell very much ;D The thing is, if I tell him to not copy the dll he wont, but the compiled program trys to find it in the bin folder anyways. That confuses me quite a lot. Is that what should happen?

Comment: Yes.  If this is a managed DLL then the only decent way to share is to put it in the GAC.  Never put anything in the GAC on your dev machine, only on the user's machine.